# Primefaces barcode width

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, barcode

I've been trying to "stretch" the barcode's width generated by primefaces, but it seems that it can't increase its width without increasing its height, does anyone know a way around it?

```
<p:barcode value="0123456789" type="code128" height="100px" width="250px" />
```

Comment: There is a good reason for a certain aspect ration. Going beyond the limits' increases the chance of scanners not being able to scan them. What is the 'actual' change you want to make? How much resizing?

Comment: Hi Kukeltje,
It is true and I'm aware of that problem with the sacanner. It would be something small like 25-35% larger width. the short height is causing it to have really thin bars and some smartphone are not able to read them.

Answer (score 0):

This is the main reason I don't use libraries or fonts. No control over output. Just plain old Javascript does the job for me at:

http://brian-p-anderson.github.io/JS-Barcodes/

Keep the width setting above 3 and height above 8 or so.